# How to email contents of a Channel Form submission with EE3x

Tags: safecracker, ee3

I set up a channel form with all custom fields... Is there an option to send an email to a recipient with all those values upon submission?  This seems like it would be such a common feature people would use but I'm not seeing it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct method. But you can initialize a email function by this hook in your extention file
https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/development/extension_hooks/module/channel_form/index.html#channel-form-submit-entry-end

Comment: That's a shame they haven't included this in Channel Forms yet.  I'm wondering if I should just go with FreeForm Pro or something cheaper that would save form to an entries channel and email someone

Comment: Free form pro is great solution but it will not save data in channel entry. No  other forms can save the data in channel entry except the default channel form

Comment: Freeform pro saves it to the database and emails... so it must just save it to it's own tables just not channels... which I'm fine with technically as long as you can pull all that data to a frontend page in the future if client wants.